# If $f(x)$ is Integrable, $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ converges and $g(x) \geq x \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to \infty} \int_{x}^{g(x)}f(t)dt = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, improper-integrals, solution-verification

Prove or disprove:

If $f(x)$ is Integrable at $[0,t], \forall t > 0$ and the integral: $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ converges and $g(x) \geq x, \forall x \geq 0$ therefore $\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_{x}^{g(x)}f(t)dt = 0$

---

What i did was to use Chushy, saying that:

$$
\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists N \in N, \forall s \geq r>N: |\int_{r}^{s}f(x)dx| < \varepsilon
$$

And this is exactly the term for limit of a function by cushy, so i conlcluded:

$$
\lim_{s,r \to \infty} \int_{r}^{s}f(x)dx = 0
$$

And specificaly we can take:

$$
g(x) = s, x = r \Rightarrow g(x) \geq x > N
$$

Therefore getting:

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_{x}^{g(x)}f(t)dt = 0
$$

Therefore the statement is true.

A friend of mine asked me how could i do the translation from $f(x)$ to $f(t)$, i mean changing from $x$ to $t$ and i didnt realy know what to tell him.

And do you think my proof is correct?

Comment: just say that you did the change of variables of definite integral, $t=x$.

Comment: also what is the difference between $\int f(a) da$ and $\int f (b) db$?

Comment: I think $a$ and $b$ are just symbols, namely, there is no different @user12986714

Comment: @user12986714 anyway, do you think my proof is correct?

Comment: then what is the difference between $\int f (x) dx$ and $\int f (t) dt$... Your proof looks perfectly fine

Comment: @user12986714 None, but i wasnt sure

Comment: Your proof is correct. You applied Cauchy criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$F(X)=\int_0^Xf(t)dt$$
for $X\ge 0$.

$\int_0^\infty f(t)dt $ converges $ \iff $ $\lim_{X\to +\infty}F(X)=L\in \Bbb R$

on the other hand, $g(x)\ge x$ for any $ x\ge 0$, thus

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}g(x)=+\infty$$

By composition of limits, we conclude that
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\int_x^{g(x)}f(t)dt=$$

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}(F(g(x))-F(x))=L-L=0$$

Comment: Sorry but I wonder, what does this have to do with the question...

Comment: @user12986714 Yes i didnt see the bound below. i edited. thanks.